# How to clean cache in Next.js / React / Chrome?

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome, caching, next.js

I have cleaned

1: Chrome all cache
2: yarn cache clean
3: remove the whole node_modules and yarn-ed again

Despite still when I am running app in Chrome I can see a parameter, was renamed before. How?

[image]

Comment: I didn't quite get the core of the problem. However, what I normally do to give next.js app a _fresh start_ - delete .next directory

Comment: You also delete `.next` folder? Good idea.

Answer (score 3):

I faced similar issue and deleting `.next` folder solved it for me

Answer (score 0):

for nextjs 13 the folder to delete is the .build

Answer (score 0):

You can delete files on the subfolders in 'cache' folder, it worked for me

Comment: Although, deleting the Cache folder, is a quicker way!